# Enable/Disable UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, cocoa, uisegmentedcontrol

Anyone know a way to reject input onto a UISegmentedControl object?

During my application loading phase, if the UISegmentedControl is tapped, the app crashes.

I've tried:

```
[segmentControl setEnabled:NO];
```

But that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Why not just make it not crash?

Comment: Disable it by default (either in your xib or when you create it), and enable it when ready.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
segmentControl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```